# Help to understand: "this Medium Rich South Asian thot"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> A “Medium Rich South Asian” was deeply moved by a beautiful and underappreciated bond that was highlighted in the film “Crazy Rich Asians.”
>
> On Monday, Mindy Kaling decided to express how much she loved the new,
>   Asian-led romantic comedy on Twitter.
>
> ```
> Quick Crazy Rich Asian thoughts from this Medium Rich South Asian thot:
>          — Mindy Kaling (@mindykaling) September 3, 2018
> ```

As I saw the very first sentence, I thought “Medium Rich South Asian” refers to 'Mindy Kaling'. But latter context changed my mind a bit, because Mindy Kaling post this on tweeter: "**Quick Crazy Rich Asian thoughts from this Medium Rich South Asian thot**". I'm kind of getting lost from here.

What does "**this Medium Rich South Asian thot**" truly mean in this context?

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/news/mindy-kaling-ugly-cried-during-221753559.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it refers to Kaling.

*This* is sometimes used to refer to the speaker. The context implies it, as you initially guessed.

"Medium" is being used to mean something like "somewhat": somewhat rich.

A South Asian person is a person from [South Asia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Asia). This prominently includes India and Kaling is of Indian heritage.

I don't want to get into too many details, but "this Medium Rich South Asian" modifies the noun "thot". "Thot" is a derogatory term towards woman. It's typically used to say a woman is sexually immodest. However, I seriously doubt she's calling herself that. I imagine she's trying to [reclaim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reappropriation) the word and is using it to mean something like "sexually empowered woman", or even simply "empowered/strong woman". She's also a comedian, so she might be trying to use it in a jocular way.

For simplicity's sake, I use "woman" for "thot". As you can tell, it's an incomplete sentence, so I make a reasonable attempt at a complete sentence. The "s" is dropped in "Crazy Rich Asian(s)" because it's modifying "thoughts" in the first line. I also change the capitalization and punctuation. And then I rephrase it afterwards.

> [Here are some] quick Crazy Rich Asian thoughts from this somewhat rich, South Asian woman.
>   → Here are some thoughts about the movie *Crazy Rich Asians* from me, a somewhat rich, South Asian woman.

Comment: Does "Thot" mean "the ho over there"?

Comment: That's one proposed origin. But that's often too literal. It's more often used as a noun with the meaning I described above.

Comment: How do you pronounce it?

Comment: To me, it rhymes with _lot_. I say /θɑt/. I imagine this will vary by dialect.